# Remove ignored files from repository

Tags: git, svn

I migrated my SVN repository to Git. I know that I have a lot of big old files in my repository, which generally should be ignored (I was noob in VCS when I started my project, so with every commit I had all my executables and libraries recreated and saved). Now this repository is well over 1.6 GB in size, despite very small code base and few assets. Now, my idea is to create .gitignore file, which will contain all generated files, like libraries, executables and other, but I want to know if I can remove all of those files, contained within my .gitignore file from all commits in my Git repository. I don't mind if Git will rewrite every commit, I just want to get rid off all those files in all commits, but I want to keep my history messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See 'git help filter-branch', especially the Examples section of it:

> git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html

Comment: Git says:

"WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
(https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1."

PS: format is not working in comments...grrr...